# How to list all the roles existing in Oracle database?

Tags: oracle

How to list all the roles existing in Oracle database?

I have been searching in the tables :

```
ROLE_TAB_PRIVS
ROLE_SYS_PRIVS
ROLE_ROLE_PRIVS

SELECT * FROM ROLE_TAB_PRIVS WHERE ROLE = 'ROLETEST';
```

but I can't find a role that I have just created.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Got the answer :

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_ROLES;
```

Comment: What I need next is a list of the Roles that would be contained in the Roles, i.e. the owner and child Roles.

Comment: Nobody has the answer?  Then I will give it:    SELECT *
FROM dba_role_privs   Gives Grantee and Granted_Role, that is you can see the sub-roles of roles.

Answer (score -1):

### all_roles.sql

```
SELECT SUBSTR(TRIM(rtp.role),1,12)          AS ROLE
     , SUBSTR(rp.grantee,1,16)              AS GRANTEE
     , SUBSTR(TRIM(rtp.privilege),1,12)     AS PRIVILEGE
     , SUBSTR(TRIM(rtp.owner),1,12)         AS OWNER
     , SUBSTR(TRIM(rtp.table_name),1,28)    AS TABLE_NAME
     , SUBSTR(TRIM(rtp.column_name),1,20)   AS COLUMN_NAME
     , SUBSTR(rtp.common,1,4)               AS COMMON
     , SUBSTR(rtp.grantable,1,4)            AS GRANTABLE
     , SUBSTR(rp.default_role,1,16)         AS DEFAULT_ROLE
     , SUBSTR(rp.admin_option,1,4)          AS ADMIN_OPTION
  FROM role_tab_privs rtp
  LEFT JOIN dba_role_privs rp
    ON (rtp.role = rp.granted_role)
 WHERE ('&1' IS NULL OR UPPER(rtp.role) LIKE UPPER('%&1%'))
   AND ('&2' IS NULL OR UPPER(rp.grantee) LIKE UPPER('%&2%'))
   AND ('&3' IS NULL OR UPPER(rtp.table_name) LIKE UPPER('%&3%'))
   AND ('&4' IS NULL OR UPPER(rtp.owner) LIKE UPPER('%&4%'))
 ORDER BY 1
        , 2
        , 3
        , 4
;
```

### Usage

```
SQLPLUS> @all_roles '' '' '' '' '' ''
SQLPLUS> @all_roles 'somerol' '' '' '' '' ''
SQLPLUS> @all_roles 'roler' 'username' '' '' '' ''
SQLPLUS> @all_roles '' '' 'part-of-database-package-name' '' '' ''
etc.
```